# DataTables.net post to return json not updating table

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables, webmethod

I have an asp.net page that successfully builds the json for return to Datatables but the page is not updated?

Here is the call from my Server.aspx page:

```
$('#displayData').dataTable( {
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bStateSave": true,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": "Data.aspx",
                    "aoColumns": [ 
                                { "sName": "id", "sTitle": "ID", "sWidth": "5%", "bSortable": "true" },
                                { "sName": "engine", "sTitle": "Engine", "sWidth": "10%", "bSortable": "true" },
                                { "sName": "browser", "sTitle": "browser", "sWidth": "10%", "bSortable": "true" },
                                { "sName": "platform", "sTitle": "platform", "sWidth": "10%", "bSortable": "true" },
                                { "sName": "version", "sTitle": "version", "sWidth": "10%", "bSortable": "true" },
                                { "sName": "grade", "sTitle": "grade", "sWidth": "10%", "bSortable": "true" }

                    ],
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                    "aaSorting": [[1,'asc']],
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sLengthMenu": "Page length: _MENU_",
                        "sSearch": "Filter:",
                        "sZeroRecords": "No matching records found"
                                },

                    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {

                        aoData.push(
                            { "name": "table", "value": "ajax" },
                            { "name": "sql", "value": "SELECT id, engine, browser, platform, version, grade" }
                        );

                        $.ajax( {"dataType": 'json',
                                 "type": "POST",
                                 "url": sSource,
                                 "data": aoData,
                                 "success": function (msg) {
                                 alert(msg.d);
                                 fnCallback(msg.d); 
                                 }
                        });

                        }
                });
```

Here is the table in the page:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="displayData"> 
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th align="left">ID</th>
                    <th align="left">Engine</th>
                    <th align="left">Browser</th>
                    <th align="left">Platform</th>
                    <th align="left">Version</th>
                    <th align="left">Grade</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td> 
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

And here is the code in the Page Load of Data.aspx (and this does return the json in str but the table on Server.aspx is not populated.

Hope you can shed some light on this.

```
  'Instanciation des variables
        'Creation of variables
        Dim str As String = "" 'Chaîne JSON en sortie - Will be the output JSON string
        Dim strClassement As String = "" 'Colonne sur laquelle le tableau est trié - Will be the sorted column
        Dim strSens As String = "" 'ASC or DESC
        Dim strSensInverse As String = "" 'DESC or ASC


        'Détection de la colonne de tri
        'Detection of sorted column
        Select Case Request("iSortCol_0")
            Case 0
                strClassement = "engine"
            Case 1
                strClassement = "browser"
            Case 2
                strClassement = "platform"
            Case 3
                strClassement = "version"
            Case 4
                strClassement = "grade"
            Case Else
                strClassement = "engine"
        End Select

        'Détection du sens du tri
        'detection of direction of the sort
        Select Case Request("sSortDir_0")
            Case "asc"
                strSens = " ASC"
                strSensInverse = " DESC"
            Case "desc"
                strSens = " DESC"
                strSensInverse = " ASC"
        End Select

        'Connexion SQL
        'SQL connection
        Try


            Using maConnexion As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("cnn_TTR").ConnectionString)

                maConnexion.Open()

                Dim dataset As New DataSet

                'Création de la requête SQL
                'SQL request creation
                Dim strRequeteA As New String("")
                Dim strRequeteC As New String("")
                Dim strRequeteB_1 As New String("")
                Dim strRequeteB_2 As New String("")
                Dim strRequeteB_3 As New String("")

                'Le requête est bâtie selon une méthode permettant la pagination avec SQL Server
                'The request is built with a method which allow pagination with SQL Server
                ' http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/
                strRequeteA += "SELECT * FROM ("
                strRequeteA += "SELECT TOP "
                strRequeteA += Request("iDisplayLength").ToString
                strRequeteA += " * FROM ("
                strRequeteB_1 = "SELECT "
                strRequeteB_2 = "TOP " + (Convert.ToInt32(Request("iDisplayStart")) + Convert.ToInt32(Request("iDisplayLength"))).ToString
                strRequeteB_3 += " id, engine, browser, platform, version, grade "
                strRequeteB_3 += "FROM ajax "

                If Request("sSearch") <> "" Then
                    If Request("sSearch") <> " " Then
                        strRequeteB_3 += "WHERE "
                        Dim chaine As String
                        For i As Integer = 0 To (Split(Request("sSearch").ToString, " ").Length - 1)
                            chaine = Split(Request("sSearch").ToString, " ")(i)
                            If chaine <> "" Then
                                If i <> 0 Then
                                    strRequeteB_3 += "AND ("
                                Else
                                    strRequeteB_3 += "("
                                End If
                                strRequeteB_3 += "engine LIKE '%" + chaine + "%'"
                                strRequeteB_3 += " OR "
                                strRequeteB_3 += "browser LIKE '%" + chaine + "%'"
                                strRequeteB_3 += " OR "
                                strRequeteB_3 += "platform LIKE '%" + chaine + "%'"
                                strRequeteB_3 += " OR "
                                strRequeteB_3 += "version LIKE '%" + chaine + "%'"
                                strRequeteB_3 += " OR "
                                strRequeteB_3 += "grade LIKE '%" + chaine + "%'"
                                strRequeteB_3 += ") "
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                End If

                strRequeteC += " ORDER BY "
                strRequeteC += strClassement
                strRequeteC += strSens

                strRequeteC += ") AS foo ORDER BY "
                strRequeteC += strClassement
                strRequeteC += strSensInverse

                strRequeteC += ") AS bar ORDER BY "
                strRequeteC += strClassement
                strRequeteC += strSens

                'Exécution de la requête
                'Request execution
                Dim MaCommande As New SqlCommand(strRequeteA + strRequeteB_1 + strRequeteB_2 + strRequeteB_3 + strRequeteC, maConnexion)
                Dim MonAdapteur As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(MaCommande)
                MonAdapteur.Fill(dataset)
                MaCommande.Dispose()

                If dataset.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                    Dim table As New DataTable
                    table = dataset.Tables(0)

                    'Ecriture des données JSON
                    'JSON data writing
                    str = "{"
                    str += """sEcho"": " + Request("sEcho") + ","

                    'Requête permettant l'écriture du nombre total d'enregistrements
                    'Request finding the total records number
                    strRequeteA = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ajax"
                    dataset = New DataSet
                    MaCommande = New SqlCommand(strRequeteA, maConnexion)
                    MonAdapteur = New SqlDataAdapter(MaCommande)
                    MonAdapteur.Fill(dataset)
                    MaCommande.Dispose()
                    str += """iTotalRecords"": " + dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0).ToString + ","

                    'Requête permettant l'écriture du nombre d'enregistrement filtrés
                    'Request finding the displayed records number
                    strRequeteA = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (" + strRequeteB_1 + strRequeteB_2 + strRequeteB_3 + ") AS P1"
                    dataset = New DataSet
                    MaCommande = New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (" + strRequeteB_1 + strRequeteB_3 + ") AS P1", maConnexion)
                    MonAdapteur = New SqlDataAdapter(MaCommande)
                    MonAdapteur.Fill(dataset)
                    MaCommande.Dispose()
                    str += """iTotalDisplayRecords"": " + dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0).ToString + ","

                    str += """aaData"": ["

                    'Procédure évitant les doublons dans la dernière page
                    'Procedure avoiding double records in last page
                    Dim nbRowANePasAfficher As Integer = 0
                    If (Convert.ToInt32(Request("iDisplayStart")) + Convert.ToInt32(Request("iDisplayLength"))) > dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0) Then
                        nbRowANePasAfficher = (Convert.ToInt32(Request("iDisplayStart")) + Convert.ToInt32(Request("iDisplayLength"))) - dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0)
                    End If
                    If Convert.ToInt32(Request("iDisplayStart")) = 0 Then
                        nbRowANePasAfficher = 0
                    End If

                    'Ecriture des données JSON
                    'JSON data writing
                    Dim autre As Boolean = False
                    For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
                        If nbRowANePasAfficher > 0 Then
                            nbRowANePasAfficher -= 1
                            Continue For
                        End If
                        If autre = True Then
                            str += ","
                        End If
                        str += "["
                        str += """" + row("engine").ToString + ""","
                        str += """" + row("browser").ToString + ""","
                        str += """" + row("platform").ToString + ""","
                        str += """" + row("version").ToString + ""","
                        str += """" + row("grade").ToString + """"
                        str += "]"
                        autre = True
                    Next
                End If
                str += "]"
                str += "}"

                Response.Write(str)

                maConnexion.Close()

            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!  Works with Asp.Net, Vb.Net, Web Forms.  Filter, sorts, paging request posts to data.aspx and return json result updates datatables.net.  All works great.  Now just need to customize all this for the real dataset.

```
$('#displayData').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "aoColumns": [ 
                { "sName": "id", "sTitle": "ID", "sWidth": "5%", "bSortable": "true" },
                { "sName": "engine", "sTitle": "Engine", "sWidth": "10%", "bSortable": "true" },
                { "sName": "browser", "sTitle": "browser", "sWidth": "10%", "bSortable": "true" },
                { "sName": "platform", "sTitle": "platform", "sWidth": "10%", "bSortable": "true" },
                { "sName": "version", "sTitle": "version", "sWidth": "10%", "bSortable": "true" },
                { "sName": "grade", "sTitle": "grade", "sWidth": "10%", "bSortable": "true" }

            ],
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aaSorting": [[1,'asc']],
            "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "Page length: _MENU_",
                "sSearch": "Filter:",
                "sZeroRecords": "No matching records found"
                        },
    "sAjaxSource":'Data.aspx'
});
```

Data.aspx now looks like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    'Instanciation des variables
    'Creation of variables
    Dim str As String = "" 'Chaîne JSON en sortie - Will be the output JSON string
    Dim strClassement As String = "" 'Colonne sur laquelle le tableau est trié - Will be the sorted column
    Dim strSens As String = "" 'ASC or DESC
    Dim strSensInverse As String = "" 'DESC or ASC


    'Détection de la colonne de tri
    'Detection of sorted column
    Select Case Request("iSortCol_0")
        Case 0
            strClassement = "engine"
        Case 1
            strClassement = "browser"
        Case 2
            strClassement = "platform"
        Case 3
            strClassement = "version"
        Case 4
            strClassement = "grade"
        Case Else
            strClassement = "engine"
    End Select

    'Détection du sens du tri
    'detection of direction of the sort
    Select Case Request("sSortDir_0")
        Case "asc"
            strSens = " ASC"
            strSensInverse = " DESC"
        Case "desc"
            strSens = " DESC"
            strSensInverse = " ASC"
    End Select

    'Connexion SQL
    'SQL connection
    Try


        Using maConnexion As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("cnn_TTR").ConnectionString)

            maConnexion.Open()

            Dim dataset As New DataSet

            'Création de la requête SQL
            'SQL request creation
            Dim strRequeteA As New String("")
            Dim strRequeteC As New String("")
            Dim strRequeteB_1 As New String("")
            Dim strRequeteB_2 As New String("")
            Dim strRequeteB_3 As New String("")

            'Le requête est bâtie selon une méthode permettant la pagination avec SQL Server
            'The request is built with a method which allow pagination with SQL Server
            ' http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/
            strRequeteA += "SELECT * FROM ("
            strRequeteA += "SELECT TOP "
            strRequeteA += Request("iDisplayLength").ToString
            strRequeteA += " * FROM ("
            strRequeteB_1 = "SELECT "
            strRequeteB_2 = "TOP " + (Convert.ToInt32(Request("iDisplayStart")) + Convert.ToInt32(Request("iDisplayLength"))).ToString
            strRequeteB_3 += " id, engine, browser, platform, version, grade "
            strRequeteB_3 += "FROM ajax "

            If Request("sSearch") <> "" Then
                If Request("sSearch") <> " " Then
                    strRequeteB_3 += "WHERE "
                    Dim chaine As String
                    For i As Integer = 0 To (Split(Request("sSearch").ToString, " ").Length - 1)
                        chaine = Split(Request("sSearch").ToString, " ")(i)
                        If chaine <> "" Then
                            If i <> 0 Then
                                strRequeteB_3 += "AND ("
                            Else
                                strRequeteB_3 += "("
                            End If
                            strRequeteB_3 += "engine LIKE '%" + chaine + "%'"
                            strRequeteB_3 += " OR "
                            strRequeteB_3 += "browser LIKE '%" + chaine + "%'"
                            strRequeteB_3 += " OR "
                            strRequeteB_3 += "platform LIKE '%" + chaine + "%'"
                            strRequeteB_3 += " OR "
                            strRequeteB_3 += "version LIKE '%" + chaine + "%'"
                            strRequeteB_3 += " OR "
                            strRequeteB_3 += "grade LIKE '%" + chaine + "%'"
                            strRequeteB_3 += ") "
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If

            strRequeteC += " ORDER BY "
            strRequeteC += strClassement
            strRequeteC += strSens

            strRequeteC += ") AS foo ORDER BY "
            strRequeteC += strClassement
            strRequeteC += strSensInverse

            strRequeteC += ") AS bar ORDER BY "
            strRequeteC += strClassement
            strRequeteC += strSens

            'Exécution de la requête
            'Request execution
            Dim MaCommande As New SqlCommand(strRequeteA + strRequeteB_1 + strRequeteB_2 + strRequeteB_3 + strRequeteC, maConnexion)
            Dim MonAdapteur As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(MaCommande)
            MonAdapteur.Fill(dataset)
            MaCommande.Dispose()

            If dataset.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                Dim table As New DataTable
                table = dataset.Tables(0)

                'Ecriture des données JSON
                'JSON data writing
                str = "{"
                str += """sEcho"": " + Request("sEcho") + ","

                'Requête permettant l'écriture du nombre total d'enregistrements
                'Request finding the total records number
                strRequeteA = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ajax"
                dataset = New DataSet
                MaCommande = New SqlCommand(strRequeteA, maConnexion)
                MonAdapteur = New SqlDataAdapter(MaCommande)
                MonAdapteur.Fill(dataset)
                MaCommande.Dispose()
                str += """iTotalRecords"": " + dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0).ToString + ","

                'Requête permettant l'écriture du nombre d'enregistrement filtrés
                'Request finding the displayed records number
                strRequeteA = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (" + strRequeteB_1 + strRequeteB_2 + strRequeteB_3 + ") AS P1"
                dataset = New DataSet
                MaCommande = New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (" + strRequeteB_1 + strRequeteB_3 + ") AS P1", maConnexion)
                MonAdapteur = New SqlDataAdapter(MaCommande)
                MonAdapteur.Fill(dataset)
                MaCommande.Dispose()
                str += """iTotalDisplayRecords"": " + dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0).ToString + ","

                str += """aaData"": ["

                'Procédure évitant les doublons dans la dernière page
                'Procedure avoiding double records in last page
                Dim nbRowANePasAfficher As Integer = 0
                If (Convert.ToInt32(Request("iDisplayStart")) + Convert.ToInt32(Request("iDisplayLength"))) > dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0) Then
                    nbRowANePasAfficher = (Convert.ToInt32(Request("iDisplayStart")) + Convert.ToInt32(Request("iDisplayLength"))) - dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0)
                End If
                If Convert.ToInt32(Request("iDisplayStart")) = 0 Then
                    nbRowANePasAfficher = 0
                End If

                'Ecriture des données JSON
                'JSON data writing
                Dim autre As Boolean = False
                For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
                    If nbRowANePasAfficher > 0 Then
                        nbRowANePasAfficher -= 1
                        Continue For
                    End If
                    If autre = True Then
                        str += ","
                    End If
                    str += "["
                    str += """" + row("id").ToString + ""","
                    str += """" + row("engine").ToString + ""","
                    str += """" + row("browser").ToString + ""","
                    str += """" + row("platform").ToString + ""","
                    str += """" + row("version").ToString + ""","
                    str += """" + row("grade").ToString + """"
                    str += "]"
                    autre = True
                Next
            End If
            str += "]"
            str += "}"

            Response.Clear()
            Response.ClearHeaders()
            Response.ClearContent()
            Response.Write(str)
            Response.Flush()
            Response.End()

            maConnexion.Close()

        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try


End Sub
```